# drawn image, converted back

Tags: image, matlab

i want to draw image, do not know how to portray the image output kmeans

my code:

```
close all; clc; clear;

img = imread('pic7.png');
figure(), imshow(img);
impixelregion;


% nastavenie noveho obrazka
[y x z] = size(img)

for i=1:1:y
    for j=1:1:x

        imgNew(i, j, :) = 0;
    end
end


[X_no_dither, map]= rgb2ind(img,8,'nodither');
figure, imshow(X_no_dither, map);
impixelregion;
m = im2double(X_no_dither)


idx = kmeans(m,4,'emptyaction','singleton');
```

how i draw image ?
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to do, as I don't think your code is doing what you think it is. Are you trying to do color segmentation?  Also, use the `zeros` function instead of that nested loop: `imgNew = zeros(y,x);`

Comment: I'm trying to use the method kmeans for clustering color image, rgb image,Sorry, the loop there should not be, I tried to combine related shades of color

Comment: In that case, your code as it is will not work, it's not just a matter of how to display the result.

Comment: Knows please help me ?, I really do not know how I did it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `kmeans`, the rows are the things we want to cluster (i.e. pixels by colour), the columns are the variables. Therefore, we cannot just pass in a image straight in, it has to be reshaped first. For example if we look at [this MATLAB example.](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/products/image/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/images/ipexhistology.html), the image is first converted into lab colorspace (and is in `lab_he`).

First, they take only the `a` and `b` elements:

```
ab = double(lab_he(:,:,2:3));
```

Then, reshape so that `ab` is of size n x m where n = total number of pixels and m = 2 - this is because each pixel is being clustered based on both `a` and `b` values:

```
nrows = size(ab,1);
ncols = size(ab,2);
ab = reshape(ab,nrows*ncols,2);
```

Now, sort those pixels into three colors:

```
nColors = 3;
% repeat the clustering 3 times to avoid local minima
[cluster_idx cluster_center] = kmeans(ab,nColors,'distance','sqEuclidean', ...
                                      'Replicates',3);
```

The result then has to be `reshape`'d back into an image to be displayed:

```
pixel_labels = reshape(cluster_idx,nrows,ncols);
imshow(pixel_labels,[]), title('image labeled by cluster index');
```

In your case, as you're using a indexed image, try something like this:

```
idx = kmeans(m(:),4,'emptyaction','singleton');
idx = reshape(idx,size(m));
imshow(idx, []);
```

`m(:)` just arranges the pixels as a single column. `kmeans` then sorts them into four clusters.  Afterwards, we `reshape` the indexes back using the size of our input image, and then display with `imshow` as normal.

You should read the linked example closely and make sure you understand what they are doing and why.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, one more question, if I have grayscale image, the procedure will be the same?

Comment: Yes, for any input image matrix which is 2D (indexed or greyscale), the last three lines should work. For an RGB image you will have to reshape it to be number of pixels x 3 (e.g. each row is the R,G,B values of one pixel).